# Converting full date into datetime in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Still relatively new to the sql language and need a little help and guidance..

I have a table which has the date in this format (2015-09-09 00:00:00) but the code I wrote pulls the date like this (Sep 21 2015 12:00AM), I would like the date to reflect like this (2015-09-09 00:00:00)

```
UPDATE table1 
SET [Column 0] = (SELECT CAST(RIGHT(LEFT([Column 1], CHARINDEX('; EndTime', [Column 1] ) -1), 19) AS DATETIME) AS Date
                  FROM table1  
                  WHERE [Column 1] LIKE '%StartTime=%')
```

Any help/guidance would be most grateful

Comment: Which **concrete** RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: You are returning a `datetime` value, it doesn't have any format at all. It gets the format when you use the value and turn it into a string, so you should change how you format it rather than to format it in the database.

Answer (score 0):

Storing the value in a date time field in SQL server means SQL will automatically convert it to the default format of your installation. Querying this will then give a consistent format.

Comment: Actually: SQL Server stores `DATETIME` as a 8-byte **binary value** which has **no format** of any kind at all ...

Comment: Isn't it actually hexadecimal? Using a generate scripts task on a date time gives back hex string,  however are we going in to much detail perhaps? I was simply suggesting writing to a table is a good way of presenting consistent results

Answer (score 0):

Here is your answer

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), YourDateColumnName, 120)+ ' ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), YourDateColumnName, 108)
```

Happy Coding